# How to deploy multiple SPFx Library components in a tenant?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

I am building for SPFx for SP Online. I want to re-use code so a SPFx Library component makes sense. However according to this

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/library-component-overview

It says:

`You can only host one library component version at the time in a tenant.`

In my case, I am going to be deploying to the tenant app catalogue but not deploy tenant wide. I will then be manually adding the Library extension app to each of my site collections.

But there will be other teams who may do the same or deploy as tenant wide in the same tenant app catalogue (our team doesn't work with other teams), as we all share the same tenant, but they manage their own site collections.

Just wanted to know would this approach work for my team? I just want to avoid conflicts with other teams SPFx Library components.

Comment: If you want to avoid conflicts then you should deploy and host library components in the site collection app catalog.

Comment: I can't do that because if my other apps are deployed at the tenant app catalogue (non tenant wide solution), how would those refer to the Library? Don't they all have to be in the same app catalogue?